# Working on Files For Print (Not 3D ! ink & paper)

Tags: rendering

working with blender for the first time,
my project is a model created from a photo, the result will be printed on paper at a
size of 1.5M X 2.5M, that's big.
any recommendation on file configuration ? should I work small in the right proportion and then scale, and if so what is the right way to do it ? how long a file like that would take to render ?
I'm trying to keep it simple and low with textures & effects. any type of advice will be great.

Comment: If you're printing a render, the only things you should need to pay attention to (other than color) are resolution and aspect ratio. Blender does not have any features around printing; it can only give you the image output, putting that on paper will be up to you.

Comment: All you need to know is how many pixels you need to render out of blender. Whatever interpretation you need as DPI is up to you.